# Resolving Visual Studio dependencies

Tags: c#, nuget

I am parsing the `project.assets.json` file in a C# project to retrieve the dependencies for a project (I'm doing this as part of a project which is extracting documentation information from the project files).

I haven't been able to find much documentation for `project.assets.json` online. It appears to have a number of sections.

Here's an extract:

```
{
    "version": 3,
    "targets": {
        "Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens/5.3.0": {
            "type": "package",
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens": "5.3.0",
                "Newtonsoft.Json": "10.0.1"
            },
            "compile": {
                "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll": {}
            },
            "runtime": {
                "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll": {}
            }
        },
    },
    "libraries": {
        "Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens/5.3.0": {
            "sha512": "GmiwCJPEe+V8+2GO3kD8K0IeqNHlTL0xZcHePIjyJveRn7OderxdT32aCZeJZEvz5w2Jlyag3zdyu1zkdTJo2A==",
            "type": "package",
            "path": "microsoft.identitymodel.jsonwebtokens/5.3.0",
            "files": [
                ".nupkg.metadata",
                ".signature.p7s",
                "lib/net45/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll",
                "lib/net45/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.pdb",
                "lib/net45/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.xml",
                "lib/net451/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll",
                "lib/net451/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.pdb",
                "lib/net451/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.xml",
                "lib/net461/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll",
                "lib/net461/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.pdb",
                "lib/net461/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.xml",
               "lib/netstandard1.4/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll",
               "lib/netstandard1.4/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.pdb",
               "lib/netstandard1.4/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.xml",
              "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll",
               "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.pdb",
              "lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.xml",
                 "microsoft.identitymodel.jsonwebtokens.5.3.0.nupkg.sha512",
                 "microsoft.identitymodel.jsonwebtokens.nuspec"
            ]
        },
    }
}
```

Conceptually, my parser looks at the targets section and extracts the path to the DLL that gets referenced by the project. For packages, that path is relative to the local nuget package repository (typically `C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages`).

But I've run into some situations -- and the extract is one of them -- where the specified DLL (`Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens/5.3.0/lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll`) doesn't exist in the local nuget repository. In fact, the libraries section shows a repository path (`Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens/5.3.0`) which doesn't exist in the repository folder (there's not even a `Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens` folder).

Yet the project with the "broken" reference builds without any errors, and functions properly.

I'd appreciate any insight others might have on how these "broken" repository paths should be resolved. If anyone knows of online documentation for `project.assets.json` that'd be great, too.

Comment: In previous versions of Visual Studio the paths for assemblies were labelled `HintPath` because it could also resolve dependencies using the Global Assembly Cache. What happens if you run `gacutil.exe /l "Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for the `packageFolders` section of the `project.assets.json` file. This is what I have:

```
  "packageFolders": {
    "C:\\Users\\zivkan\\.nuget\\packages\\": {},
    "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\NuGetFallbackFolder": {}
  },
```

`Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens` sounds a lot like something that would be used by ASP.NET Core, and therefore the .NET Core SDK NuGetFallbackFolder sounds like a very likely place for it to be.

By using the package folders listed in the json file, your program will also be more robust if used on a project that redirects its global packages folder away from the default user profile location.

Comment: thanx, @zivkan! Besides solving my specific problem you also resolved an issue I knew I was going to have to deal with but hadn't yet: that the default locations for repository folders can be changed.